# How to wait for a job to join when job itself contains another job? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

This is a scaled down version of the code we currently have. I know it seems trivial in the example, but in production we are sending a message to the server and awaiting its response (which is why it needs to be async).

The goal is to have the "Hello World" message print at the end, i.e. after both foo() and bar() are done. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
fun foo() = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    for (i in 1..5) {
        println("waiting for response from server A $i...")
    }
    bar()
}

fun bar() = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    for (i in 1..5) {
        println("waiting for response from server B $i...")
    }
}

suspend fun main() {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) { foo() }
    job.join()
    println("Hello World")
}
```

which prints

```
waiting for response from server A 1... 
waiting for response from server A 2...
waiting for response from server A 3...
waiting for response from server A 4...
waiting for response from server A 5...
waiting for response from server B 1...
waiting for response from server B 2...
waiting for response from server B 3...
Hello World
waiting for response from server B 4...
waiting for response from server B 5...
```

Comment: Make `bar` a suspend function and use` withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` instead of launching a new coroutine. Or replace the `bar()` call with `bar().join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` for functions `foo()` and `bar()` you can call `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` which calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result - [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) :

```
suspend fun main() {
    foo()
    println("Hello World")
}

suspend fun foo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        println("waiting for response from server A $i...")
    }
    bar()
}

suspend fun bar() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        println("waiting for response from server B $i...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like @Andrei Tanana 's example, it works about 80% of the time, but it fails 20% of the time

Comment: @ElSushiboi I've edited my answer, please take a look, it should work.

Comment: hmmm...i'd really like say it works, but still fails occasionally :(

Comment: @ElSushiboi, I've edited the answer again :) Suggest to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` function instead of `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: Thanks Sergey! This works 100% of time time. I also like how it's really clean!

Answer (score 1):

you can use job as follow

```
private suspend fun bar()  {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        for (i in 1..5) {
             println("waiting for response from server B $i...")
        }
    }
    job.join()
    println("Hello World")
}

private suspend fun foo() {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        for (i in 1..5) {
             println("waiting for response from server A $i...")
        }
    }
    job.join()
    bar()
}

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { foo() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works 100% of the time. I'm giving you an upvote for it, but i'm giving the "solved" to @Sergey as his solution is slightly cleaner.